# Facebook Pixel + Google Tag Manager + fbq events

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I'm using Google Tag Manager to deliver Facebook Pixel.

Then, I fire events using code like this

```
  <body>
...
        <script>
            fbq('track', 'ViewContent', { 
                content_type: 'product',
                content_ids: ['1234'],
                content_name: 'ABC Leather Sandal',
                content_category: 'Shoes',
                value: 0.50,
                currency: 'USD'
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

But when the code is executed I got an error since Facebook Pixel is loaded asynchronously and fbq is not available yet.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fbq is not defined

What should I do?

Answer (score 19):

Couldn't get Eike's approach to work and ended up with the below "dirty workaround" (basically it just waits till the fbq is inited):

```
<script>
    function waitForFbq(callback){
        if(typeof fbq !== 'undefined'){
            callback()
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                waitForFbq(callback)
            }, 100)
        }
    }

    waitForFbq(function () {
        fbq('track', 'Registered');
    })
</script>
```

Maybe it will help someone as well

Answer (score 10):

Use the tag sequencing feature. This allows to fire tags in a predefined order, where the subsequent tags wait for the previous ones before they are executed.

Create a tag that loads the FB init code. Select "Once per page" in the tag firing options (you need to load this only once, even if it used by multiple tags).

Go to your Facebook event tag. In the advanced settings look for the tag sequencing options. Set it to:

[image]

(where Facebook init is your tag that loads the FB library, I am asumming that you use their standard bootstrap code). With the last checkbox enabled this will not fire if your setup tag has failed.

Since the FB bootstrap code will set up a fbq object with a command queue you can now push data to fbq; even if the library is still downloading the data will enter the command queue and the calls will be executed when the library has been downloaded.

The tag sequence makes sure that the fbq object is set up before your event. If this is your only FB event you can save yourself the trouble and simply paste the loader above your event code.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I found your answer as I am also getting the 'fbq is not defined' error even when I am already sequencing my tags correctly. I have the Setup-tag set to the Facebook base pixel, but only the INIT part. I fire the PageView event separately that also is using the Base Pixel as its setup-tag. I wonder, does Facebook want the PageView event o have fired before any other event as well or is the INIT part of the pixel enough for all events to work regardless of PageView?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Viru us solution actually solves the problem because the OP requires that the event code is on the actual template page (presumably to pull in template variables which GTM cannot do)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error - in the end it was all about sequencing.

When used through tag manager on a wordpress site through the WP plugin, the pixel was loaded in the footer by default, so the fbq variable used before being declared in the footer, was not recognised in the body:
[Google Tag Manager for WordPress options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdSwS.png)

I tried different settings, and in the end gave up using the plugin - simply inserted it in the header section using the script section of my page builder (Thrive Architect = TA):
[Custom script setting in TA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS3hO.png)
and it all works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

#### Proper way to handle a problem like this

You need to check if the window reference exists, not if its value is null!

While you can't use:

```
if (fbq !== undefined) {
  // browser code
}
// or 
if (window.fbq !== undefined) {
  // browser code
}
```

Because this would try to compare a non-existent variable (window) to undefined, resulting in the mighty "ReferenceError: window is not defined". You can still use:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // browser code
}
```

Because typeof won't try to evaluate "window", it will only try to get its type,

Comment: Yeah you got rid of the crash, but your analytics won't initialise properly and you'll screw your reports if you follow this approach. In the context of question you are literally just hiding the problem, not solving it. Don't use this code.